# What caused my Entity Framework database context to fail to generate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

**Is there something that can cause an Entity Framework database context to fail to generate its files, need reboot before being able to again (and that may also change the default debugging project)?**

My details:

So I have an existing, working, in-production ASP.NET MVC 3 web application that uses Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, being built in Visual Studio 2010.

The other day, I don't think I had done anything other that edit one line in a CSHTML file (removing two Razor references to DateTime), when it suddenly started failing to build, reporting this:

> C:...\DataLayer.cs(38,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FooEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:...\DataLayer.cs(57,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FooEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I.e., the Entity Framework database connection was somehow broken. The file which usually defines FooEntities is auto-generated by Entity Framework, to a file which was left essentially empty. Usually it auto-generates a definition file, where the reference to FooEntities looks like:

```
public partial class FooEntities : ObjectContext
```

The FooData.edmx file still appeared in the IDE, but at first it did nothing when I tried to regenerate it with "Update model from database". After a Windows 7 reboot, that update did run without complaint and resulted in that definition file regenerating. The solution then built without errors.

However after I did that, I also found that the DataLayer project was now marked as the (bold-text) default project to debug, not the UI project. **Is there something that would automatically change that, or some shortcut I could have accidentally hit to change that?**

I went to my source control and did a diff, and there was no unexpected nor relevant change in my source code or config files - only in the .suo and auto-generated entity framework files (.\datalayer\obj\debug\designtimeresolveassemblyreferencesinput.cache    .\datalayer\datastore.context.cs).

Problem seemingly solved, has anyone else seen something like this, or have a guess what could have caused it?

Answer (score 1):

The change of the start-up project was caused by the modified .suo file. This [Solution User Options file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) stores personal settings concerning a specific solution, among which the start-up project. This information is not stored in the .sln file.

I'm not aware of any .suo settings that could affect the code generation form an edmx file, but it could be related.

The lesson to learn here is: **never commit .suo files to source control**. They contain *your* settings, even absolute paths that most likely apply to your machine only (unless each developer has exactly the same folder structure). So by updating your source from the source control repository, your settings may get overwritten by some one else's settings.

Comment: Thanks, that's good relevant information, and clearly it could explain the change to the start-up project in cases where there are multiple users or if I had restored from some old suo file. In my case I don't think it caused this instance because I am the only current developer and I have been working out of the same local dev folder for months only doing check-ins to source control and not updating from source control to that folder since I have been working alone from one dev computer. The .suo change in diff does show that the settings changed and were saved to file though.